# Kernel error : [drm] Resetting GPU

Tags: kernel, driver, gpu

I am using an app which is using the vc4-drivers. Sometimes videos freeze for an instant, and I see a kernel message saying :

```
[drm] Resetting GPU
```

After that, some font are no more displayed but the app still runs.
I have tried to disable those drivers in */boot/config.txt*, but I need them...
I have although tried to improve *gpu_mem* from 256 to 512, but it does not help...

Any idea ?
Thank you !

Etienne

Comment: chances are it's a power supply issue

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX, I have just changed the power supply, it seems to be better, but the issue is still happening sometimes.... I am using 5V-3A output power supply, do you think it could still be an issue ?

Comment: Could it be the gpu is overused and don't have time to communicate with the cpu anymore so it resets ? If so, how could I debug it ? Thanks

Comment: Well, it may not be that then ... I just googled the error, and regarding RPi that was the first result - perhaps you can search `raspberry pi [drm] Resetting GPU` and see if you can find anything

Comment: Thanks, for the moment, my googling did not lead to anything successful

Comment: I confirm this does not come from power supply. I have ran tests with 2 other power supplies, an official one from pi and a lab one.